# How to evaluate $\sum_{r=1}^{n}n-r$

Tags: summation

I have an equation as:

$\sum_{r=1}^{n}n-r$

When I evaluate it, I get the result as:
= (n-1)+(n-2)+..+(n-n)
= ?

Comment: Add up the "$n$" terms first. Then add up the subtracted terms. Then subtract.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $\sum_{r = 1}^n (n-r) = n^2 - \sum_{r=1}^n r$. Now you should be able to give a close form of $\sum_{r=1}^n r$.

Answer (score 3):

***Hint***: \begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{r=1}^n n-r &=& (n-1)+(n-2)+\cdots + 1+ 0 \\ &=& 0 + 1 + \cdots +(n-2)+(n-1) \\ &=& \sum_{r=1}^{n-1}r.\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: So, that is nC2

Comment: yep, ${n\choose 2}$.